# if...elif statement in python/pandas

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, pandas, split

I am working on a script that sorts people's names. I had this working using the csv module, but as this is going to be tied to a larger pandas project, I thought I would convert it.

I need to split a single name field into fields for first, middle and last. The original field has the first name first. ex: Richard Wayne Van Dyke.

I split the names but want "Van Dyke" to be the last name.

Here is my code for the csv module that works:

```
with open('inputfil.csv') as inf:
    docs = csv.reader(inf)
    next(ccaddocs, None)
    for i in docs:
        #print i
        fullname = i[1]#it's the second column in the input file
        namelist =fullname.split(' ') 
        firstname = namelist[0]
        middlename = namelist[1]
        if len(namelist) == 2:
            lastname = namelist[1]
            middlename = ''
        elif len(namelist) == 3:
            lastname = namelist[2]
        elif len(namelist) == 4:
            lastname = namelist[2] + " " + namelist[3] #gets Van Dyke in lastname
        print "First: " + firstname + " middle: " + middlename + " last: " + lastname
```

Here is my pandas-based code that I'm struggling with:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Richard Wayne Van Dyke','Gary Del Barco','Dave Allen Smith']})
df = df.fillna('')
df =df.astype(unicode)
splits = df['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

df['firstName'] = splits[0]
if  splits[2].notnull and splits[3].isnull:#this works for Bret Allen Cardwell

    df['lastName'] = splits[2]
    df['middleName'] = splits[1]
    print "Case 1: First: " + df['firstName'] + " middle: " +df['middleName'] + " last: " + df['lastName']
elif splits[2].all() == 'Del':#trying to get last name of "Del Barco"
    print 'del'
    df['middleName'] = ''
    df['lastName'] = splits[2] + " " + splits[3]
    print "Case 2: First: " + df['firstName'] + " middle: " +df['middleName'] + " last: " + df['lastName']

elif splits[3].notnull: #trying to get last name of "Van Dyke"
    df['middleName'] = splits[1]
    df['lastName'] = splits[2] + " " + splits[3]
    print "Case 3: First: " + df['firstName'] + " middle: " +df['middleName'] + " last: " + df['lastName']
```

There is something basic that I'm missing.

Comment: I haven't figured out the pandas, but have revised my csv code which will do the work before passing the data to pandas. Instead of using `csv.reader` as in the csv code above, I changed it to `csv.DictReader`. By passing the data to a dictionary, it was easy to use the key value pairs for the Name field to get the csv code to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(name) >= 3: # (assume that user only has one middle name)

  firstname = splits[0]
  middlename = splits[1]
  lastnames = splits[2:] ( catch all last names into a list )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see your logic, but when I print "lastnames" I get: >>> 
      0      1      2     3
2  Dave  Allen  Smith  None
>>>    I'm not sure what's going on, here. I expected to see  a list of the last names. When I changed lastnames to `splits[2] + splits[3]` i get: >>> 
0    VanDyke
1        NaN
2        NaN
dtype: object
>>>

Comment: have you tried just printing the splits to see what is actually there?

Comment: yes:
0    Richard
1       Gary
2       Dave
Name: 0, dtype: object
0    Wayne
1      Del
2    Allen
Name: 1, dtype: object
0      Van
1    Barco
2    Smith
Name: 2, dtype: object
0    Dyke
1    None
2    None
Name: 3, dtype: object